# Soundcloud Widget throws "404 Oops, we couldn’t find that sound" as song is playing

Tags: soundcloud

Was there a recent update to the basic Soundcloud widget?

I currently have two playlist widgets on a website. Now, when I click on a song, the song plays and as the song is ending, the player throws a "404 – Oops, we couldn’t find that sound."  Strange thing is the songs ends normally and the player continues to stream the next song in the list. When I click the "Go Back" link on the 404 page, the player loads the first song of the playlist.

Thank You for any assist or insights. George

FOLLOWUP: I deleted the second playlist and recreated it thinking it may solve the problem. Mistake. I get a 404 saying it can't find the playlist! Very embarrassing since we were previewing songs for an upcoming EP release.

Comment: Hey, could you please let us know the URL of the playlist perhaps? It can either be a mix up of the privacy / sharing settings of playlists / tracks within it or a bug. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

i just had a similar issue, and i think it's a bug to do with privacy settings not being correctly updated when you publish a playlist/set as a whole.

in my situation, i had 5 tracks that were in a set, with only one of them public and the set itself set to private. then i made the set public and said "make all the tracks public too".

after doing this, i created my widget and had the aforementioned 404 error about 50% of the time (if i hit refresh sometimes it would work, but if i hit refresh again, it would break again).

i seem to have fixed it by editing one of the recently published tracks and hitting save again.  now i can't get the 404 error re-appear. hopefully that's going to continue and hopefully this helps SC engineers diagnose the issue here..